# How to give URL for Home page from Spring MVC on Heroku

Tags: spring, jsp, heroku, jstl

I have looked and tried everywhere without success so posting this question.

Recently deployed a working Spring MVC app on Heroku platform, it was a pleasant experience for the most. How ever the spring url tag or even jstl core url tag are behaving differently on Heroku, than on my local tomacat server.

for example my links '>Sign in would be perfect resolves to http: //mydomain:port/context/signin on my local but after deploying the Heroku it would /signin as absolute path, so i quickly removed and it is working good.

However i have a home link on my nav bar that is '>Home   if I remove the forward slash then the Home link is essentially point to what ever is my current url on address bar instead of context home.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after going through couple of other similar questions and answers, the below approach solved my problem on Heroku for Home page link.

```
created a <base/> element in <head> as below

<base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}
:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

then in jsp the code below started resolving correctly on Heroku

```
<a href='<s:url value=""></s:url>'>Home</a>
<s:url value="signin"></s:url>'>Sign in</a>
```

how ever for my local tomcat deployments to work i had to append an extra forward slash to the above

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}
:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
```

since this code is only in my base template I guess I will have to live with this one file descrepency between my local and deployed versions

I would love to see any wholesome answers

Answer (score 3):

From experience what works best for me is not to hardcode your link with `/` on the left, but create this "root" variable on your jsp:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

Then in your jsp whenever you need reference root path:

```
<img src="${root}/resources/mycoolpic.png"/>
```

Other variation is you can use html `<base..>` tag to set where `/` refer to but this make your code more obscure and hard to understand. For example:

```
<base href="my-root">
<img src="/resources/mycoolpic.png"/>
```

Will actually resolve to /my-root/resources/mycoolpic.png

Comment: Added an option of using html `<base..>` to my answer